# How to reference static functions in Unity inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, static-methods, scriptable-object

I have a scriptable object class Attack and created some assets from it.

In the Attack asset inspector, I want to be able to reference static functions from other classes, so when something happens, I can grab this static function referenced in Attack and execute it.

Is that possible?

---

I tried an asset called UltEvents (which claims to get this task done) but it didn't seem work in the newest Unity LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UnityEvent` should work, here's an example.

Add a `UnityEvent` property as usual. The static `RunTest` method is the callback, the `TestCallback` is used to invoke the event.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Attack")]
public class Attack : ScriptableObject
{
    public UnityEvent callback;

    public static void RunTest()
    {
        Debug.Log("Run Test");
    }

    public void TestCallback()
    {
        callback?.Invoke();
        Debug.Log("TestCallback");
    }
}
```

To select the callback in the inspector, there are 2 situations:

1. You have an asset/instance associated with the callback, in this example because I define it in the `Attack` class, the instantiated scriptable object is the asset, you can directly select the callback from the inspector.

   [image: inspector mode]
2. You don't have an asset/instance, you need to switch the inspector to the debug mode and manually populate the callback, see the 2nd screenshot. Pay attention to these fields: `Target Assembly`, `Method Name`, `Mode`, `Call State`. If the callback needs an argument, you should also fill in one of the `Arguments` field.

   [image: debug mode]

Now if everything is OK, you can see "Run Test" in the console when you call `TestCallback`.

---

**Alternative 1**

The 2nd solution seems like a trick, you can imitate it in a customized way:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyStaticCallback
{
    public string TypeName, MethodName;
    private Action _callback;

    public void Invoke()
    {
        _callback ??= (Action)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action),
            Type.GetType(TypeName), MethodName);
        _callback?.Invoke();
    }
}

public class Attack : ScriptableObject
{
    public MyStaticCallback callback;
}
```

---

**Alternative 2**

Since the callback is static, you can solve this problem in a static way by defining derived classes for each kind of callbacks.

```
public class Attack1 : Attack
{
    public override void RunCallback() => AnyType.AnyStaticMethod();
}
```

Comment: I ended up using the option 2 (the one with debug inspector). This is kind of crazy and should be something that was built-in (something like dragging a script file into the inspector and choosing a static function). Your option is the best I can go now.

Comment: I'm wondering if this solution uses reflection (since it needs the strings of the class and function name)... if it does, is there a way I can cache the function somehow to avoid reflections after the first execution?

Comment: UnityEvent uses reflections too, alternative 1 is its simplified version which caches the delegate.